Emojis are shown in black and white in MS Word
I recently reinstalled Windows 10 and also reinstalled the fonts and Microsoft Word. Prior to the reinstallation, emojis were displayed in color. However, after the reinstall, they appear in black and white. I’ve also tested this in OpenOffice and WordPad, with the same result.
Interestingly, they still appear colorful in Visual Studio Code. Additionally, I tested my font packs (Segoe UI Emoji and Twemoji Mozilla) at this link: https://wakamaifondue.com/, and they display in a colorful theme.
I came across this topic on Super User (Emojis are only in black and white in MS Word), but unfortunately, the answers provided there didn’t work for me.
Any insights into why this issue is occurring and how I can restore the colorful display of emojis in Microsoft Word and other applications would be greatly appreciated!
at Ms-Word 
at VS-Code

Does this answer your question? Emojis are only in black and white in MS Word

No, I tested all the answers in that link. None of them work for me.  I Think my problem is something with windows fonts. I reinstalled some fonts and fixed the windows default fonts from registry. but the problem still exist.

At least I could solve this problem for MS-Word.
First, I noticed that there were two "seguiemj.ttf" files in the Windows fonts. I found this using the Windows Font Viewer (open Windows 10 Settings, then select 'Fonts' from the Personalization section). One of them was an old version, which caused Windows to use it for displaying emojis.
Replacing the old version with the newer one at least fixed the corrupted emojis in my browser and VSCode.
I also reset the Windows font settings to default using the following registry code:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black (TrueType)"="seguibl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black Italic (TrueType)"="seguibli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Emoji (TrueType)"="seguiemj.ttf"
"Segoe UI Historic (TrueType)"="seguihis.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"="segoeuil.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light Italic (TrueType)"="seguili.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"="seguisb.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold Italic (TrueType)"="seguisbi.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight (TrueType)"="segoeuisl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight Italic (TrueType)"="seguisli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"
"Segoe MDL2 Assets (TrueType)"="segmdl2.ttf"
"Segoe Print (TrueType)"="segoepr.ttf"
"Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)"="segoeprb.ttf"
"Segoe Script (TrueType)"="segoesc.ttf"
"Segoe Script Bold (TrueType)"="segoescb.ttf"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]

"Segoe UI"=-

Photo of vscode after fixing the segoe emoji font file:

For MS-Word, I updated my 2016 version of MS-Word to the latest version, and the problem was fixed.
However, it's interesting that my previous Windows installation on my old HDD showed colorful emojis with the 2016 version of MS-Word, while the new installation of the same version on Windows 10 does not display colorful emojis. (Please see the attached photo). Additionally, if I'm not mistaken, I could see colorful emojis in WordPad on my old Windows 10 installation, but the new one only displays black and white emojis.

